# Chess Board counting problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, problem-solving, chessboard

**Consider a n x n chess board. Count the number of shortest paths from the position (0,0) to the position (100,100) if each move can either be a horizontal step or a vertical step. You may assume that n is larger than 100.**

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each move can be either $(x,y)\to(x+1,y)$ (we call it "h") or $(x,y)\to(x,y+1)$ (we call it "v") so a shortest path is sequence of $100$ "h" and $100$ "v" mixed up in
$$\frac{200!}{100!\cdot 100!}={200\choose 100} \hbox{ ways.}$$